# Jenkins: Unable to find remote helper for 'https'

Tags: jenkins

We have client server (RHEL 6.4) and git and Jenkins are installed on the same server and when i tried to paste the clone URL in to Jenkins i am getting the following errors. Please help

**Failed to connect to repository : Command "/usr/local/bin/git ls-remote -h https://Sivakrishnan@bitbucket.org/rentokilinitial/newui.git HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'https'**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you installed GIT from source and you are missing `curl-devel`.

You should install (lib)`curl-devel`

For more dependency needed if you install GIT from source, can be found here:

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Installing-Git

Comment: Thanks for your help and it works perfectly